# How to add FreeType library to my Android Studio native project with Cmake

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, freetype

I am making a native Android Opengl ES 2.0 application on Android Studio.
I would like to link FreeType library to my project so that I can render texts.

My project uses Cmake, I am guessing that I have to use `add_library` but I need the .a static library files. How can I build them ? (I am on Windows but I can switch to Linux if it's easier to build)

And my second problem is, the target architecture. So I will have to build the static libraries for different architectures (armeabi-v7a, armeabi, mips, x86). And on my Cmake file I would need to add the correct .a files depending on the architecture, how do I know what am I targeting ?

Comment: You can get the `*.so` from an emulator or an actual device, should be `/system/lib/libft2.so` since Android uses FreeType2 internally. As for the header, copy it from a Windows build and change the config appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to cmake. Add to cpp forder freetype forder.

```
add_subdirectory(freetype)

target_include_directories(projectname PRIVATE
    freetype/include)

target_link_libraries(
  ....
  freetype
  ....
 )
```

Comment: While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.